# Contain groups in Auth info CakePHP 3

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I'm looking for a CakePHP 3.x update [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785551/getting-associated-models-with-this-auth-in-cakephp). Basically, I am authenticating users using the `Auth` component in CakePHP 3 and need to include `groups`.

My model relations are as follows:

```
User hasMany Groups
Group hasMany Users
```

So basically it's a many-to-many relationship.

Currently, my login function looks like this:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('login');
}
```

Is there a way to do this with the `Auth` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was pretty easy:

I changed my login function to this:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $user = $this->setUserGroups($user);
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            die(debug($this->Auth->user()));
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'),['params'=>['class'=>'test']]);
    }
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('login');
}
```

Then I created the `setUserGroups($user)` function

```
/**
 * @param AuthComponent $user
 * @return TableRegistry $this
 */
private function getUserGroups($user)
{
    $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');

    $query = $users->find()
        ->contain(['Groups'])
        ->where(['users.id' => $user['id']])
        ->limit(1);
    return $query;
}

/**
 * @param AuthComponent $user
 * @return AuthComponent mixed
 */
private function setUserGroups($user)
{
    $results = $this->getUserGroups($user);
    $user['groups'] = [];
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        foreach ($row->groups as $group) {
            $user['groups'][] = $group['id'];
        }
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Now it returns my user object with an array of group id's.

Comment: You better use a [**custom finder**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query).